# SSH sometimes is refused on domainname but not on ip

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have a domain myname.com. Normally I access the server using ssh user@myname.com.
Some days, I get the message

```
ssh: connect to host myname.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Ssh by ip works fine. Leaving it for a few hours/days. The issue is resolved by its own.
I also noted that accessing other open ports, for example myname.com:10001, is not possible anymore.
Seems that the issue is that ports are not accessible anymore!

I have doubts that this has to do with the hosting provider. Would you share your thoughts on the matter?

EDIT:
 - I tried nmap to scan for open ports

```
nmap myname.com
```

> Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-06-05 13:38 CEST
>   Nmap scan report for myname.com (192.168.x.y)
>   Host is up (0.0058s latency).
>   Other addresses for myname.com (not scanned): xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
>   rDNS record for 192.168.x.y: myname.com.myname.com
>   Not shown: 992 closed ports
>   PORT      STATE SERVICE
>   22/tcp    open  ssh
>   ...

The reverse DNS showed that the domain somehow is duplicated 'myname.com.myname.com'.

under /etc/hosts I found the following:

127.0.1.1 myname.com
192.168.x.y myname.com

Which line should I keep ?

Comment: So where is the server you are trying to connect to? If it is somewhere on the internet, then both of those host file entries are wrong.

Secondly can you run 'hostname' and 'domainname' in terminal and share the results. I wonder if your hostname and domain name are both set to myname.com.

Comment: hostname was myname.com; domainname retruned (none).

Answer (score 0):

The first problem sounds like a DNS issue. If it works sometimes and not others by DNS name but always works by IP, I'd say there is an issue with your DNS zone. Probably mis-matched name servers.

The second problem is hard to answer without more information. Do you have SSH configured to accept connections on random ports? Is there any kind of firewall in front of it? Do you have a dedicated host or is it part of some shared web hosting plan?

Comment: I tried to scan open ports on the domain. The report showed that rDns is myname.com.myname.com.